# Azure function can't create a local folder (python)

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm using Azure functions and I want to make a local folder, where I can put a file and copy it to a blob storage.

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#upload-blobs-to-a-container
where they just call `os.mkdir(local_path)` to create the (temp) folder.
Based on the tutorial I do:

```
logging.info('before folder creation')
# Create a local directory to hold blob data
local_path = "./data"
logging.info('inside folder creation')
os.mkdir(local_path)
logging.info('after folder creation')
```

and I'm getting:

```
2023-10-04T19:31:30Z   [Information]   before folder creation
2023-10-04T19:31:30Z   [Information]   inside folder creation
... and fail


wrapping the code in a try block and catching the exception releals this error:
[Errno 38] Function not implemented: './data'
```

The error looks strange but it really just looks like it can't create the folder.
What should I do to allow Azure function to create the folder?

Comment: Try "/tmp/data" instead

Comment: this works to me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure function to execute you code, you need to use triggers.
I have used HttpTrigger named **"HttpTrigger1"** to execute my code.

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    try:
        logging.info('before folder creation')
        # Create a local directory to hold blob data
        local_path = "./data"
        logging.info('inside folder creation')
        os.mkdir(local_path)
        logging.info('after folder creation')

        return func.HttpResponse("folder created",status_code=200)
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error:{ValueError}",status_code=500)
```

**`Output`:**

`Before executing the code`:

[image]

`After`:

[image]

[image]

Folder created in current directory:

[image]

**EDIT:**

**In Azure:**

with `"./data"`

[image]

with `"/tmp/data"`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but have you tried it on Azure? You seem to be using localhost.

Comment: @user2743931 In Azure It will throw error. I agree with @Dean MacGregor. you need to use `"/tmp/data"` to run and execute in Azure.
Edited Answer.